# Where should I ask a question about e-ink displays?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which is the right Stack Exchange site to ask how to use an e-ink display as an external Display for your PC?

I already asked here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574589/is-it-possible-to-connect-an-e-ink-tablet-as-second-external-monitor

but that seemed to be the wrong place.

I also have some more questions about this subject.

Comment: Your question there yielded an answer that was deleted: http://www.techhive.com/article/259582/how_to_use_a_kindle_dx_as_a_pc_display.html#tk.hp_new

Comment: Yes, that's already a nice option, but since I have more questions about this, I wonder where to ask now?

Comment: Superuser maybe?  I'm not suggesting you post there, but I am suggesting that maybe you could read the [Superuser FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) to see if their site would take it. I don't spend a lot of time there, but it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit strange. I found this question there, that is voted up:

https://superuser.com/questions/188812/e-ink-screens-for-desktop-pc

and this question, that is closed as "off topic":

[Is there any non-prototype laptop with e-ink display?](https://superuser.com/questions/202583/is-there-any-non-prototype-laptop-with-e-ink-display)

So why is that second question closed? It is really interesting.

Comment: Second one is requesting a specific product,which I guess was seen as "shopping recommendation" which is off topic in their FAQ. I'd have closed as Not Constructive, but it seems questions about actually doing something (as opposed to "does this product exist") should be on topic on Super User